# Printing Column Names and Values in Dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

The end goal of this question is to plot X and Y for a graph using a dataframe.

I have a dataframe like so:

```
             Open    High     Low   Close     Volume       stock symbol
Date                                                              
2000-10-19    1.37    1.42    1.24    1.35  373590000         AAPL
2000-10-20    1.36    1.46    1.35    1.39  195836200         AAPL
2000-10-23    1.39    1.49    1.39    1.46  129851400         AAPL
2000-10-24    1.48    1.49    1.34    1.35  192711400         AAPL
2000-10-25    1.36    1.37    1.30    1.32  163448600         AAPL
2000-10-26    1.34    1.42    1.25    1.32  178110800         AAPL
2000-10-27    1.35    1.37    1.28    1.33  181242600         AAPL
2000-10-30    1.37    1.42    1.34    1.38  152558000         AAPL
```

And I am trying to plot `Date` vs. `Open`. I know there is a way to simply plot, but I will be applying this concept to larger dataframes and would like to know how to do it "long-hand".

**What I've tried:**

`print(some_DF['Open'])`

Result:

```
 Date
    2000-10-19      1.37
    2000-10-20      1.36
    2000-10-23      1.39
    2000-10-24      1.48
    2000-10-25      1.36
    2000-10-26      1.34
```

**Problem:**

Date seems to be my index, but the column header 'Open' Does not appear.

**Question:**

How do i print the above Dataframe while having `'Open'` as my header. Then making some value `x`=`Date`'s column and some value `y` = `'Open`'s values?

**"Expected Code to work":**

Im thinking something like

```
print([some_DF['Open'] headers = 'date','open')
x = some_DF['Date'] #So that this becomes first column of dataframe
y = some_DF['Open'] #So that this becomes second column of dataframe
```

Comment: what's the data file like? the first 10 lines will do. I'm curious how you read that data file, and what the raw file looks like

Comment: Have you tried `print(some_DF[['Open']])`?

Comment: @M.Klugerford this is very close to what i'd like. However, the 'Date' and 'Open' headers look to be on different rows. Could you explain what the double `[[`  `]]` is doing?

Comment: @Tuan333 it's from panda's DataReader from yahoo finance.

Comment: @MattR it's because one is the index, the other a column, so their names are on different rows so you don't confuse them.

Comment: It's funny, it's the third time in two days I see someone worried about how the pandas output looks. Do you have a specific reason for that? What matters is the graph you want...

Comment: @IanS i guess it's my OCD or something. But I really don't mind if `x` is the first column and `y` is the second

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can `reset_index` on the data-frame and then print the subset dataframe consisting of the two columns

```
>>> df
            a  b
Date            
2000-10-19  1  3
2000-10-20  2  4
2000-10-21  3  5
2000-10-22  4  6
2000-10-23  5  7
>>> print(df.reset_index()[['Date', 'a']])
        Date  a
0 2000-10-19  1
1 2000-10-20  2
2 2000-10-21  3
3 2000-10-22  4
4 2000-10-23  5
```

Like IanS mentioned, you shouldn't worry about how the output looks in pandas. Date was an index and Open a column. The difference in the print statement illustrates that distinction.

Edit:

The `df[[list_of_column_names]]` is the same as `df.loc[:, [list_of_column_names]]`. It gives a list of columns to subset the original dataframe.

Comment: restet_index... why didn't i think of that. Great! Now how would i make `x` the first column and `y` the second? any tips?

Comment: @MattR with your original dataframe you could do `print(some_DF.reset_index()[['Date', 'Open']])` The order of the output depends on the order you provide the list of column names.

Comment: I'm still confused on what the `[[ ]]` is doing. Would it be possible to explain that? I really appreciate the help